# How do I add an additional database for migration?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a Drupal 8 site running in [Lando](https://docs.lando.dev/). I need to have the 8 site connect to a Drupal 7 database so I can run a migration.

My understanding is I can import an additional database through Lando, but from the documentation I cannot figure out exactly how to do this.

I've tried adding this to my **.lando.yml**:

```
services:
  legacydatabase:
    type: mysql
    creds:
      user: root
      password:
      database: legacy
```

and then multiple attempts at the **lando db-import** command to no avail.

I need to know what exactly goes in .lando.yml and then what exactly goes in the lando db-import arguments to get this working.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track. You can use

```
services:
  legacydatabase:
    type: mysql
```

And do a `lando rebuild` to spin up a second DB server. If you did not specify the credentials you can check them with `lando info`.

To use db-import (or export) you have to specify which host to use. By default it uses 'database' and not `legacydatabase` or whatever you called your second DB server. As per the [documentation](https://docs.devwithlando.io/guides/db-import.html):
Options:
  --host, -h      The database service to use                  [default: "database"]

So the command to use in your case would be:

`lando db-import --host legacydatabase [your_mysql_file]`

Comment: This worked great for me. Just wanted to note that I am running lando v3.0.0-rc.22. I was then able to run ```lando drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-url=mysql://mysql:mysql@legacydatabase.APPNAME.internal/database```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I think it was a DB size issue. My legacy database was ~20GBs, and it just hangs for hours.... I try to check the container logs, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```yaml
services:
  database2:
    type: mariadb
```

The creds will be set as:

```yaml
"creds": {
  "user": "mariadb",
  "password": "password",
  "database": "database"
},
```

Comment: This looks good, but I think you need to add another level of indenting for `type`.

Comment: @RoloDMonkey good eye. I corrected the YAML indentation. Those pesky semantic whitespace errors can be hard to debug.